# How to find $\int_{0}^{\infty} \log(1+x)(x^a)\exp(-bx) dx$ step by step?

Tags: integration

How can I find $\int_{0}^{\infty} \log(1+x)x^a\exp(-bx) dx$ step by step?

I've got a Mathematica solution, but I'd like to know and understand the steps taken to reach the solution.

On page 469 of "Integrals and Series" by A.B Prudnikov, Yu. A. Brychkov, O.I. Marichev, there is a solution to this integral:

[image]

However, I'd like to know the steps involved in this derivation even if it is necessary to take non-elementary functions during that derivation.

Comment: this is not an integral that can be done in terms of elementary functions, for example, for $a=0$ it's the exponential integral function.

Comment: Dear Carlo, you are right. Mathematica gives the answer in terms of non elementary functions. however , would it be possible to find a step by step  solution to that integral in terms of non elementary functions ?

Comment: the solution in this questions seems to help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134643/how-we-can-integrate-int-0-infty-xn-1-logx-exp-ax-exp-bx-dx-and

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo: your question in your comment has a trivial answer (yes).  The function you have written down is tautologically a non-elementary function, so your expression has already been written as one.

Comment: I'm guessing you do not want the solution with $L_n^\lambda$ in there?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, yes, if that is feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's investigate
$$
L(k,b) := \int_0^\infty \log(1+x) x^k e^{-bx}dx
\tag1$$
where $k$ is a nonnegative integer, and $b>0$.
I assume we already know
$$
E(k,b) :=\int_0^\infty x^k e^{-bx} dx = \frac{k!}{b^{1+k}} 
\tag2$$
We can evaluate
$$
\widetilde{E}(n,b) := \int_0^\infty (1+x)^n e^{-bx} dx
\tag3$$
as a linear combination of $E(k,b)$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n$.

Now write $(1)$ as a linear combination of
$$
\widetilde{L}(n,b) := \int_0^\infty \log(1+x) (1+x)^n e^{-bx} dx
\tag4$$
with $n=0,1,\dots,k$.
Integrate $(4)$ by parts to get
$$
\widetilde{L}(n,b) = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} 
+ \frac{b}{n+1}\widetilde{L}(n+1,b)
- \frac{b}{(n+1)^2}\widetilde{E}(n+1,b)
\tag5$$
Using the reduction formula $(5)$, together with the known values $(3)$,
everything reduces to evaluation of
$$
\widetilde{L}(0,b) = \int_0^\infty \log(1+x) e^{-bx} dx 
= \frac{e^b}{b} \operatorname{Ei}_1(b)
$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}_1$ is the "exponential integral" function
defined by
$$
\operatorname{Ei}_1(z) = \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-tz}}{t} dt
$$

---

Example:
$$
\widetilde{L}(5,b) = \frac{20 e^b}{b^6}\operatorname{Ei}_1(b)
+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{9}{b^3}+\frac{47}{b^4}
+\frac{154}{b^5}+\frac{274}{b^6}
$$

---

Note: I did $(1)$ only for $k$ a nonnegative integer; not for general real values of $k$.

Comment: Dear, thanks for your answer. I'm still a bit confused on how to use it to calculate the integral in my question. Thanks.